# Questions about media rating bodies

Tags: discussion, tags

We have [esrb](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esrb) - it has some questions on it that belong on that tag, we don't appear to have any questions raised for any of the other major rating bodies;

- ACB, the Australian media rating system.
- ESRB, the United States and Canadian computer and video game rating system
- ELSPA, the former British computer and video game rating system, replaced by the PEGI system.
- PEGI, the European computer and video game rating system
- USK, the German computer and video game rating system
- OFLC, the New Zealand media rating system
- GRB, the South Korean computer and video game rating system.
- Eirin, the Japanese film rating system.

We do have questions mentioning these bodies though. Would it be worthwhile creating a new tag to encompass all related questions to the correct tag (we have some questions on [version-differences](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-differences) for example that would be better under a generic media-ratings tag) and then synonym the others to that so that in future any such questions get raised under this new tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's worthwhile to create a new tag: rather, I think these should be handled like the [platform tags](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4638/platform-tags-are-useless):

- If the question is *about* the ratings body, it should be tagged with the ratings body. Right now, we only need [esrb](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esrb)<sup>1</sup>, as nobody seems to be interested in asking questions about the other bodies. If someone does ask a question about a different ratings body, we should create a tag for that ratings body then and there.
- However, if a question merely *mentions* a ratings body and that mention is incidental to what the question wants to know ([example](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28395/how-can-i-identify-the-regional-version-of-painkiller-resurrection-from-the-disc)), the question should be left untagged.

<sup>Note 1: to that end, I'm not sure why the DO NOT USE tag wiki was added to it: it's [not currently part of the tag cleanup](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/4758/131), and it doesn't run into any of the problem categories [outlined by Oak](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4636/sorting-out-the-tagging-mess). I've gone ahead and approved your tag wiki suggestions removing that notice.</sup>

Comment: I 90% agree with this, though I'd argue for a canonical tag [tag:content-ratings] or similar with [tag:esrb] and others as synonyms as needed.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Why? I'm not seeing the benefit over the status quo: [tag:esrb] isn't being abused, and creating [tag:content-ratings] creates a new, potentially abusable category 6 tag that's currently only synonymous with ESRB.

Comment: @MarkTrapp re: 1 - I began burning and then rolled back, I submitted a separate tag wiki after this, and then raised this question - thanks for accepting my amended tag wiki submission.

Comment: @Mark because the subject matter is generally similar across various ratings boards and it minimizes the risk of, say, a [tag:grb] question ending up untagged.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz the ESRB questions we have are specifically about ESRB practices; one's knowledge of one rating system doesn't apply to the others: for example, knowing PEGI's age-gating policies doesn't inform you of what the ESRB's policies are. And [nobody's asking GRB-specific questions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=grb), so there's no risk of them getting untagged.