# Are questions about comparisons of Adults-only games vs their Teen/Mature counterparts allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have read that [sexual content is not allowed](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/607/are-questions-about-adult-themed-games-allowed) and [questions about media rating bodies are](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5156/questions-about-media-rating-bodies), but there are Adults-Only (AO) rated games with no sexual content and other ones with an Everyone/Teen rating that are suggestive/borderline illegal (in some countries).

Let's say that I want to know the differences between the [Adults Only](https://www.esrb.org/ratings/27610/Manhunt+2/) and [Mature](https://www.esrb.org/ratings/23558/Manhunt+2/) versions of Manhunt 2:

- Is this type of question allowed?
- If so, What is acceptable or not on this content?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**As long as both the question and its answer(s) heed the general Code of Conduct, I think there is no problem.**

There is inherently nothing wrong about asking a question like that, as long as you exclude potential filter keywords, explicit imagery or links to potentially harmful websites.

In this particular case, the *Adults Only* rating is used for the PC version of Manhunt 2, probably since one of the major differences is that "*the executions are uncut and uncensored*" <sup>*</sup>. I don't think phrasing it like that violates the CoC or is particularly disturbing to the gaming community.

<sup>* [source](https://manhunt.fandom.com/wiki/Manhunt_2_Version_Differences).

One of the differences between the *Mature* and the *Adults Only* ESRB ratings are "*prolonged scenes of intense violence*" ([source](https://www.esrb.org/ratings-guide/))</sup>

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because I found a question that asks if the [Steam version of Fahrenheit/Indigo Prophecy is censored (M) or not (AO)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/2985/199843) (not directly, but I feel that it still counts).

Comment: @Lemon - also, check out the [tag:version-differences] tag